# Androidx SeekBarPreference xml attribute setMax not found

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-preferences

I'm trying to implement androidx SeekBarPreference, according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/SeekBarPreference.html) I might be able to use `setMax` attribute in my xml, yet I get the following error when doing so:

in xml:

```
<SeekBarPreference
    app:key="preference_key"
    app:title="@string/preference"
    app:showSeekBarValue="true"
    app:setMax="10"/>
```

the error:

```
root_preferences.xml:53: AAPT: error: attribute setMax (aka 
gls.dev.MyApplication:setMax) not found.
```

However, when setting the properties in code it works like a charm:

```
findPreference<SeekBarPreference>("preference_key")?.apply {
    max = 10
    min = 1
    seekBarIncrement = 1
    isAdjustable = true
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `max` attribute currently only exists in the android: namespace, so you will need to use:

```
<SeekBarPreference
    app:key="preference_key"
    app:title="@string/preference"
    app:showSeekBarValue="true"
    android:max="10"/>
```

Comment: using app:max => `Error: attribute max not found`, using android:max => `error: unbound prefix.`

Comment: Is there a reason the max attribute does not exist in the app namespace? I'd assume it should, as literally all other attributes for the `SeekBarPreference` exist as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can set up your seek bar like this:

```
        <SeekBarPreference
        app:title="Choose value:"
        app:defaultValue="2"
        app:min="2"
        app:seekBarIncrement="1"
        android:max="12"
        app:key="key"
        app:adjustable="true"
        app:isPreferenceVisible="true"
        app:showSeekBarValue="true"/>
```

You'll also need to add this to your root tag:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is `max` not `setMax`. You have to do:

```
app:max="10"
```

Comment: I doesn't work for me, the error persists `root_preferences.xml:53: AAPT: error: attribute setMax (aka 
gls.dev.MyApplication:setMax) not found.`

Comment: The error is saying setMax, not max. Are you sure you did change app:setMax to app:max?

Comment: sorry I just pasted the same error than before, the error now says `root_preferences.xml:54: AAPT: error: attribute max (aka gls.dev.MyApplication:max) not found`

Comment: Try using `android:max` instead of `app:max`, as @Louis is suggesting

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

In your XML

```
<SeekBarPreference
    app:key="preference_key"
    app:title="@string/preference"
    app:showSeekBarValue="true"
    app:max="10"/>
```

It will work